# Rewrite $\frac{a}{x-Sy}$ to $\frac{K}{S}$? It's possible?

Tags: fractions

I have the following challenge:

Rewrite this fraction:

$$ \frac{a}{x-Sy} $$

where **$a$**, **$x$** and **$y$** are constants and **$S$** is a variable.

To this fraction:

$$\frac{K}{S}$$

where **$K$** is a constant.

If its possible, then what are the steps to rewrite the fraction?

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for is not possible.  If $S=0$, the first expression is $\frac ax$ but the second expression is undefined.  Conversely, if $S=\frac xy$, then the first expression is undefined but (assuming $x \neq 0$) the second expression exists.

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible when $a \neq 0$.  If this were possible, you'd have $K=\frac{aS}{x-Sy}$ which is supposed to be a constant. With $S=0$ you get $K=0$.  Hence $\frac{K}{S}=0$ regardless of what $S$ is, so $\frac{a}{x-Sy} = 0$ regardless of what $S$ is.  Hence $a=0$.

When $a=0$ this is possible by taking $K=0$.

Answer (score 0):

As long as $S$ isn’t zero,
$$\textrm{anything}=\frac{\textrm{anything}\times S}{S}$$
So necessarily
$$K=\frac{aS}{x-Sy}=\frac{a}{\frac{x}{S}-y}.$$
This can’t be constant unless $a$ is zero (in which case $K$ is also zero) or $x$ is zero (in which case $K$ is $-\frac{a}{y}$).